# Check duplicated indices for each subset of values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df_test = pd.DataFrame(data=[['AP1', 'House1'],
                             ['AP1', 'House1'], 
                             ['AP2', 'House1'], 
                             ['AP3', 'House2'], 
                             ['AP4','House2'], 
                             ['AP5', 'House2']],
                       columns=['AP', 'House'],
                       index=[0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1])
```

I need to check at each subset of values of a column and see if there are duplicated indices. For example, in column `House`, we have three entries of `House1` and no duplicated indices. But for entry `House2` we have one duplicated index `1`.

I have tried this:

```
print(f'{df_test.index.duplicated().sum()} repeated entries')
```

But this gives `3` duplicated entries, since it does not consider each value of the column separately.

Comment: What is your exact expected output?

Comment: @mozway The number of duplicated indices at each of the subset values of a column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution:

```
print(df_test.reset_index().duplicated(['index', 'AP']).sum())
print(df_test.reset_index().duplicated(['index', 'House']).sum())
```

Output:

```
0
1
```

Comment: I have to say I don't understand how this answers the question. Did I miss something?

Comment: @mozway: maybe the OP is in better position to answer your question. ;-)

Comment: Yes of course ;)

Comment: After a good night, I understood the logic! +1.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
>>> (df_test.reset_index(names='Dups')
            .groupby('House', as_index=False)['Dups']
            .agg(lambda x: x.duplicated().sum()))

    House  Dups
0  House1     0
1  House2     1
```